# How to limit number of displayed images within one field under views?

Tags: views, media, entities

I've created a content type **News** with different fields, one of the fields is **field collection** that allows administrator to upload unlimited images with a detailed description text.

I used **Views** module to display a list of news on the homepage, now I want to limit the number of displayed images within field collection to **max 2** per news and when users clicks on the news to see full detail page they will be able to see all images that have been added by administrator.

Is there a way to limit number of items in the frontend but keep unlimited in the backend (admin)?

Comment: I'm quite sure Views already handles this. Have you checked what settings are available when you select the field for the view?

Comment: Yes you're right, I was not paying attention to it "Multiple field settings" configuration. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use field collection in Views, go to the settings of field collection field in views and follow these steps :

```
1. There is a setting named "Multiple Field Setting"
2. Enter the number of pictures in the textfield you want to show in Field 'Display'
```

and you also specify Start from to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this you need direct access for the image field that exist in the field collection, so you need to add relation to field collection and then you add that image field directly.

In this way you will have control over the image field only, not the whole field collection, then you can limit the number of images in the Multiple Field Setting.